# Make use_trans_sid work (Append Session ID to URL)

Tags: php

I am losing hair over this. All I want is to append the Session ID to the URL. To explain why I accept the security risks: the site is meant for mobile use. Some mobile browsers do not accept cookies (in which the Session ID is usually stored). So I don't have much of a choice but to parse the Session ID via the URL.

"So," I thought, "this is easy. Just use this at the beginning of every page:"

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
session_start();
```

Bummer. Didn't work. Ok. Then I created a .htaccess in my subdirectory (the mobile site lies in a subdirectory of the main site) with this in it:

```
php_flag session.use_trans_sid on
php_value session.use_trans_sid 1
```

No effect. Getting mad.

Next I tried to change the setting in the php.ini itself just to test it (not an option, since the rest of the websites running on the webserver must not use the "URL-Session-ID"). So I made sure this entry is set:

```
session.use_trans_sid = 1
```

Then I restarted the webserver and... to my astonishment but not surprise: NO EFFECT!

In each case I added phpinfo(); at the end of my page to see whether my settings take effect. In every case I got confirmation that session.use_trans_sid = 1 (according to phpinfo()).

This means I must overlook something. Anyone an idea?All I can do now is manually add the Session ID to every link in my code. Please help me avoid this... :)

Any ideas all you stars out there? ;)

BiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... this was indeed it. [Olirav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547210/olirav) found the issue.

The whole system doesn't work when a redirect is done somewhere. With every form and every link I call the same page, run it through a central file where I do stuff and then redirect accordingly. That effectively kills use_trans_sid. This means in that central file I must add the sid actually manually. Something like this:

```
header("Location: " . $url . "index.php?sid=" . session_id());
```

I hope that this helps someone who ever has the same problem. :)

Thanks [Olirav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547210/olirav)!!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this in a normal browser, because if the browser supports cookies the url wouldn't be added?

Comment: Testing it on both. I should mention that I also tested it with the settings

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);

so as to disable the use of cookies completely. To no avail. But thanks for the tip. Good hint.

Comment: Can I have a look at this site, might be able to help more?

Comment: Also could try adding php_flag session.use_trans_sid On (Not with the value feild as well) to htaccess to see if that makes a difference. Value is for a string, flag is for a boolean - using both could be interfering with itself

Comment: Sorry. Cannot provide access at the moment. I can provide more code, though. I removed the php_value session.use_trans_sid 1 from .htaccess. Still no change. Thanks for thinking about this...

Comment: I was looking here for a way to send a private message (am still new to these boards), but seem to not be able to. Is there a way to contact you? I could create you a time-restricted account so you can take a look.

Comment: Done. E-Mail sent. Of course, as I mentioned, a solution, albeit not a good one, is to simply append the session id to every link on the website.

Comment: Have got email I'll have a look a little later.

Comment: Just had a quick look and it looks like the link you are using that loses the session is doing a get request and the SID is only added to POST form submissions, im planning to have a proper look in an hour or so so I could be wrong.

Comment: Got it. The post request is going to the right place but when you post /mobile/index.php?navid=sms with phone_number_verification=1 your PHP sends a 302 header("Location....") redirect trying to refresh it. Through inspecting the traffic you can see the add a number page is actually being shown then redirected away from.